# how to generate new type based on existing type by manipulating properties with pattern in Typescript

Tags: typescript

For a base type like this:

```
interface BaseObject {
  name: string;
  age: number
}
```

I want to create a new type based on the existing type so I can create a patternized new object like :

```
const afterTransform: Transformed<BaseObject> = {
  useName: () => '',
  useAge: () => 1
}
```

the type of the value changed to a function returning the original type, and the name of the key has an extra prefix `use` with the 1st letter being uppercased.

How to do that in Typescript,

I played with the new template literal syntax without any luck:

```
interface Transformed<
    BaseType extends BaseObject, 
    Key extends string & keyof BaseType, 
    CapitalizedKey extends Capitalize<Key>
> {
  [`use${CapitalizedKey}`]:  () => BaseType[Key]
}
```

Or, is this even possible with the current Typescript, what happens here is we need to create new properties on existing type.

[image]

If you want to play with it, this is the [Typescript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QPICMBWECYyA3gFDLIhwC2EAXMhmFKAOYDclyc7j1AK61c0cgF9y5UJFiIUAFShwQGGAHso9ACYAedFgUBPAA4oIAD0ghtGNJhwEiYADTIA0hCPJL1281YOZAAyZABrL3UYe0NTCDcAYTgTYDA4ABtgAC8IbU9vXwgbOySUtMyc3XyAPmqyHgBtAANBLAASUlLUjOzc-PEmgF0mZAAKAEpkAF46gwhjMwb8wYkpBHVVEjgYWSUVNU1aJj3VDS1c-Qc8QmI6qfqqVogAOToBAHJ3lx4ngEF%20JgARgkQA).

Comment: This is a textbook example from the doc: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using mapped types with [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as):

```
type Transformed<BaseType> = {
  [Key in keyof BaseType as `use${Capitalize<string & Key>}`]: () => BaseType[Key]
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QPICMBWECYyA3gFDLIhwC2EAXMhmFKAOYDclyc7j1AK61c0cgF9y5MAE8ADigAqUOCAwwA9lHoATADzosi+RAB8yALxkeAbQDSEGclDIA1o40w0mCMYW8MZAADQSwAElIAYTg5YDA4ABtgAC8IPRY2EHZkADJkBxlTcSCAXSYACgBKS3NDXxN7RxKJKQQNNRI4GEgoZVV1LVomPrVNbQh9OrxCYnMrCipQiAA5OgEqmuQAci2AGh4lgEF+CuqLcwBGCSA)

Comment: lord, did not know we can do an `as` in type definition! Looks like too flexible. does not matter, Problem solved! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
type Transformed<BaseType extends BaseObject> = {
   [K in `use${Capitalize<string & keyof BaseType>}`]:  () => BaseType[keyof BaseType]
}

const tr: Transformed<BaseObject> = {
    useName: () => '',
    useAge: () => 42,
}
```

As @Alksey L. pointed out, it's only almost correct :). His answer is correct.

Comment: `() => BaseType[keyof BaseType]` will result in `() => string | number`

Comment: @AlekseyL.  Yes, I already noticed... Your answer is better ;)