# Create new type based on existing type transforming keys

Tags: typescript

I am trying to interface two systems, each with a different format type (JSON - camelCase into snake_case) in TypeScript.
I want to be able to create only one type and from this create the other one.

Example:

```
// [camelCase sys] I am creating this type
type consumerSchemaCamelCase = {
  categoryName: string, //  camelCase
}

// [snake_case sys] This other type would "infer" from the previous
type consumerSchemaCamelCase = {
  category_name: string, //  snake_case
}
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67717005/11061371)  is almost what I need, but my implementation requires a more advanced string manipulation for each key.

```
type Transformed<BaseType> = {
  [Key in keyof BaseType as `use${Capitalize<string & Key>}`]: () => BaseType[Key]
}
```

This would be one way to implement the transformation:

```js
const remapKey = (inputKey: string): string => inputKey.replace(/[A-Z]/g, x => `_${x.toLowerCase()}`);
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Regarding converting keys of `ConsumerSchemaCamelCase` to `ConsumerSchemaSnakeCase`: You can create a recursice [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) helper type and then use a [Mapped Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to map all of the keys.

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwghgWwgG3gZwgFQPYGUB2cA1hOhADyZQQAewE+AJmlGsAE4CW+A5gHxQAvFCq16TFgAMAJAG9uAMwjsoAVQC+cxcqgA1dZKgB+ALAAoKFBmzV1Og2aw4YTsDjJOALwqqBRqABEAPoBUABcgQGasgAy2ADuygDGcBjkvtHwSKipWHiEJGTkunwG4SIA3ObmoJCw2PhoAK5I7LhJABYQCHBZKGRCULLmlin0PNjsIAByiBARbFy8ADTm6tVmtdAwDc2t7V09BMSkuYPDFlAA2gDSUNxO2WQ4x4W55CQg2Ar1jS3KB26vTmOQwfAAugsONweGsgA)

```
type CamelCaseToSnakeCase<T extends string> = T extends `${infer U}${infer V}` ?
  `${U extends Capitalize<U> ? "_" : ""}${Lowercase<U>}${CamelCaseToSnakeCase<V>}` : T;

type ConsumerSchemaCamelCase = {
  categoryName: string,
}

type ConsumerSchemaSnakeCase = {
  [K in CamelCaseToSnakeCase<keyof ConsumerSchemaCamelCase>]: string
}
```

Comment: `U extends Captialize<U>` will do all kinds of fun things to non-letters, you might want to change that (try `base64Hash` for example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) inside of a [tail recursive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#tail-recursion-elimination-on-conditional-types) to convert camel-cased string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) to snake-cased versions:

```
type CamelToSnake<T extends string, A extends string = ""> =
    T extends `${infer F}${infer R}` ?
    CamelToSnake<R, `${A}${F extends Lowercase<F> ? "" : "_"}${Lowercase<F>}`> :
    A
```

That works by outputting the lowercase version of all the characters, and prepending a `_` to any character whose lowercase version is different from the original (so `A` will become `_a` and `Z` will become `_z` but `a`, `z`, `3`, and `!` will stay the same).

Then you can use a [mapped type with key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to convert objects with camel-cased properties to those with analogous snake-cased properties:

```
type CamelPropsToSnakeProps<T> =
    { [K in keyof T as K extends string ? CamelToSnake<K> : K]: T[K] }
```

Let's test it out:

```
type ConsumerSchemaCamelCase = {
    categoryName: string,
    base64Hash: string;
    youCanDoThisWithVeryLongPropertiesIfYouWantAndItShouldStillWorkUnlessYouHaveLikeAThousandCharactersInTheStringButThatWouldBeCrazy: number;
}

type ConsumerSchemaSnakeCase = CamelPropsToSnakeProps<ConsumerSchemaCamelCase>;
/* type ConsumerSchemaSnakeCase = {
    category_name: string;
    base64_hash: string;
    you_can_do_this_with_very_long_properties_if_you_want_and_it_should_still_work_unless_you_have_like_a_thousand_characters_in_the_string_but_that_would_be_crazy: number;
} */
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-riLHSQK8wK0Pkhvn8AUDQeChqRoQg5JCMGKBv5hm2yF8fv8LDWwRDOhhG0oiwB6ABU8Dan0rfcBIMH9fTBNhRnhidgSJRhSI6CpUaLGng+PSJMKfqYlIkR-pSsKqQIhQYOEKfM5hQSvOBhSdu4wb4eEKaBenFSVpUKThTEKBkv1VcBCm9KDEOvPUGEKNhOGNL8zUKX4rRtWCHz9J1CgwV1YCQ99dV+L1GEfP0AyDCwmCg58+SorFeEKXE4xoxNcJTDCC0fLMc3gPNUALdgixseBJ3HFogA)